# Grails- Assigning associated domain objects into List vs ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have this relationship:

```
User{
...
hasMany = [tags: Tag]

}

Tag{
...
}
```

Some where in my service I have this code:

```
List<Tag> tags = user.tags
```

But this does not work, I am getting this error:

---

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[com.app.ext.Tag : 1]' with class 
'org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet' to class 'java.util.List' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.List(com.app.ext.Tag)
    at ConsoleScript15.run(ConsoleScript15:6)
```

If I change my code to:

```
ArrayList<Tag> tags = user.tags
```

It works as expected! though `ArrayList` is subclass of `List`.
*Any explanation?*

Grails version: **2.3.0**

Comment: `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet` is a `Set`, not a `List` btw. So it's clearly why it cannot cast in fist case, but have no explanation why it can cast to `ArrayList`. Maybe interface vs class difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Groovy's [casting rules](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Internals#GroovyInternals-CastingRulesinGeneral).

When value which you try to cast is collection, constructor of the type you want to cast to is invoked. So, for `ArrayList` it implicitly invokes:

```
ArrayList<Tag> tags = new ArrayList(users.tags)
```

For `List` it would be something like `new List(users.tags)` which is incorrect since `List` is interface.

The snippet below shows the same problem:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>(['A', 'B'])
ArrayList<String> myList = mySet; // works okay
List<String> myList = mySet; // fails with GroovyCastException
```

But you can explicitly cast to `ArrayList`:

```
List<String> myList = mySet as ArrayList;
```

Comment: @BurtBeckwith My answer is an explanation on why implicit cast from `Set` (`PersistentSet` in this case) to `List` fails. Both answers (your and mine) are helpful imho, I explain the main source of problem (the exception, I read it) and your answer is more 'wider'. I'm not sure if it's a good reason for downvoting...

Answer (score 2):

When you define a `hasMany` property, the format is a Map. Your pseudocode is incorrect, using { } instead of [ ]. The real code probably looks more like

```
static hasMany = [tags: Tag]
```

`Tag` specifies the collection member type as the `Tag` domain class, and `tags` can be any legal variable name. Typically it's the lowercase and plural form of the class name, but that's just a convention.

An AST transformation uses this information to compile into your class a `Set` property named `tags`, essentially this:

```
Set<Tag> tags
```

and if you had used a different name, e.g.

```
static hasMany = [puppies: Tag]
```

then you'd have

```
Set<Tag> puppies
```

A `Set` isn't a `List` and vice versa - sets guarantee uniqueness, and lists guarantee order.

You can convert one to the other very easily in Groovy, and if that's what you were trying to do, then the other answer should be helpful. But given that the original type is a `Set`, adding the items to a `List` makes no sense because the order will be random.

You can declare the type of the collection to be a list, and Hibernate will add an additional column to store the element indexes to ensure that the order in the list is preserved in the database. To do that, explicitly add in a `List` declaration

```
List tags
static hasMany = [tags: Tag]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question to ` [tags: Tag]`, also it is really helpful.

Comment: It would also be advisable for you to check the grails guide at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#domainClasses

Answer (score 0):

It would also be advisable for you to check the grails guide, it is being stated there that a **hasMany**  relationship is a Map by default http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#domainClasses, if you want otherwise, you explicitly have to declare the variable as a Set

```
  public class Car{
      Set<Tyre> tyres

      static has many = [tyres:Tyre, seats:Seat]
 }
```

In this case, uniqueness would be ensured for tyres because is a Set while it wouldn't for the seats because it is a Map by default

Hope this helps too

Comment: Only the `hasMany` declaration is a Map, but that's _completely_ irrelevant as far as Hibernate and GORM are concerned. This is just the way that you declare the configuration information. It could have been an annotation, or external configuration in XML, but in Grails it's a static `hasMany` property. But the resulting collection is a `Set` by default (your `Set<Tyre> tyres` is redundant as the AST adds that for you, which you can see when decompiling) and can be a `List` if you add `List<Tyre> tyres`.